# DSL optional WHERE clause based on a parameter

Tags: where-clause, jooq, querydsl

I am new to JOOQ and DSL, this is the problem that I’m currently trying to solve. I have a simple method that returns a list of users with a certain status from a database table:

```
public List<User> getUser (String status) {
        return dsl.select()
                .from(Users.USERS)               
                .where(Users.USERS.STATUS.eq(status))
                .fetch()
                .map(…);
```

In my request, I can also specify the name of the users that I want to be included in that list, so the “name” parameter is not mandatory.
Is it possible to add an optional WHERE clause to my database query, which will only be considered if the “name” parameter is not null?

```
public List<User> getUser (String status, String name) {
        return dsl.select()
                .from(Users.USERS)               
                .where(Users.USERS.STATUS.eq(status))
                .and(OPTIONAL WHERE CLAUSE DEPENDENT ON WHETHER ‘NAME’ IS NULL OR NOT)
                .fetch()
                .map(…);
```

Among the DSL-methods suggested by the IDE I didn’t find anything that looked like it would help in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Every jOOQ query is a dynamic SQL query, as stated in the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), so you can just dynamically add your predicates to your various clauses:

#### Using local variables:

```java
Condition condition = USERS.STATUS.eq(status);

if (name != null)
    condition = condition.and(USERS.NAME.eq(name));

dsl.select()
   .from(USERS)               
   .where(condition)
   .fetch()
```

#### Using expressions:

```java
dsl.select()
   .from(USERS)               
   .where(USERS.STATUS.eq(status))
   .and(name != null ? USERS.NAME.eq(name) : noCondition())
   .fetch()
```

[See the example about optional conditions in the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/no-condition/).

#### Other ways

There are many other ways, it doesn't really matter to jOOQ *how* you construct a jOOQ query. A query is just a bunch of method calls that happens to look quite a bit like a static query, but it isn't static, and you decide which methods to call in what order and with what arguments.

Comment: Hey @Lukas, thank you very much, the solution works perfectly! Now the way those queries are constructed makes much more sense, and so I can add as many conditions to a query as I need to.